# VBA: I change arr(0), can't understand why arr(1) is changed?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
Call MakeRoomForArrayItem(interAll, 0)

interAll(0).StartY = tempStartY
interAll(0).K = tempK
```

In the first line I successfully create a new elongate interAll() by one.

Then I expect lines two and three to only affect interAll(0), but they perform the same changes to interAll(1). Why is this? Did I not successfully create a new object for interAll(1)?

```
Sub MakeRoomForArrayItem(ItemArray As Variant, ByVal ItemElement As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim Preserve ItemArray(LBound(ItemArray) To UBound(ItemArray) + 1)

    For i = UBound(ItemArray) - 1 To ItemElement Step -1
        Set ItemArray(i + 1) = ItemArray(i)
    Next
    'Erase values in object ItemArray(ItemElement) would be nice
End Sub
```

I have used the same function successfully in other cases. Could it have to do with missing declarations in the calling function?

EDIT: I fixed the problem by adding

```
Set interval = New CInterval
Set interAll(0) = interval
```

Can you explain to me what really happened here so that I don't make the same mistake again?

Comment: Psst ... don't forget to upvote comments you found helpful, and accept the answer you found the most helpful! (It doesn't have to be mine!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of variable you are passing into `MakeRoomForArrayItem`. If your array is holding a value type variable, such as Integer or Boolean, then it will work, because the assignment statement

```
Set ItemArray(i + 1) = ItemArray(i)
```

is copying a value.  But if you are using a variable that is passed by reference, then you are not copying its value, but rather, you are copying the reference to the variable. In this case, you appear to be passing a class variable, which would be passed by reference.

EDIT: When you made the call to `New CInterval`, you actually allocated a new variable, instead of copying a reference to the previous variable. That is why your fix worked. Without your fix, you only had one "slot" in memory to hold a value, but your array referenced that memory multiple times. After your fix, you had as many "slots" in memory as you had calls to `New CInterval`, and each element of the array referenced the new memory location.

Perhaps the following code will help:

```
Set interval1 = New CInterval   ' you have a single CInterval instance
Set interval2 = New CInterval   ' changes to interval1 or interval2 do not affect each other
Set interval3 = interval2       ' changes to interval3 also make changes to interval2,
                                ' because they are the same object.
Dim arr as CInterval(3)        
' Create a single array that has 3 elements, 
' which will hold 3 references to CInterval instances.  
' Those references may or may not be to the same actual CInterval instance.

Set arr(0) = interval1   ' the first element of the array references the first object instance
Set arr(1) = interval1   ' the second element of the array also references the first object instance
Set arr(2) = interval2   ' the third element of the array references the second object instance. 
                         ' Changes to this element will affect both interval2 and interval3, because they are references to the same object in memory.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

`Set ItemArray(i + 1) = ItemArray(i)`

You are copying a reference, not a value. So at the end of the loop, when `i=0`, what this line is saying is "copy a reference to the object in `ItemArray(0)` to location 1."  Thus both `ItemArray(0)` and `ItemArray(1)` contain references pointing to the same object instance.  You should be able to confirm this with the debugger.